# Filtering quantity by month by product in D3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am new to D3.js and I have issues with reading data from a csv file. Currently my dataset has 3 columns: 1) Date, 2) Product Name, 3) Quantity. I wanted to display my quantity sold per month. As of now, I use a PivotTable to filter the data by months, save as a new csv file, before parsing it to d3.csv method to display in a bar chart.

Ideally, I want to use d3.js to read from my original dataset to display the bar charts of my quantity sold by month. Also, I want to be able to filter my bar charts to display the quantity sold by products as well

e.g. If i choose Product A through the dropdown box, the bar charts will transform accordingly to show the quantity sold of Product A in January, February.... all the way to December.

Can anyone help me with this? Or link me with an example/tutorial to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want, but you can find many exemple and documentation in d3.js website (http://d3js.org/).

Edit:

You can do something like this (I just hard code the data but it's easy to adapt):

html:

```
<svg id="visualisation" width="1000" height="500"></svg>
```

js:

```
var dataC = [{
  'x': 'p1',
  'y': 5
}, {
  'x': 'p2',
  'y': 20
}, {
  'x': 'p3',
  'y': 10
}, {
  'x': 'p4',
  'y': 40
}, {
  'x': 'p5',
  'y': 5
}, {
  'x': 'p6',
  'y': 60
}];
InitChart(dataC);
function InitChart(barData, child) {
  var vis = d3.select('#visualisation'),
  WIDTH = 500,
  HEIGHT = 500,
  MARGINS = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50
  },
  xRange = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right], 0.1).domain(barData.map(function (d) {
    return d.x;
  })),
  yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0,
    d3.max(barData, function (d) {
      return d.y;
    })
  ]),
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xRange)
    .tickSize(5)
    .tickSubdivide(true),
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yRange)
    .tickSize(5)
    .orient("left")
    .tickSubdivide(true);
vis.append('svg:g')
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ')')
  .call(xAxis);
vis.append('svg:g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (MARGINS.left) + ',0)')
  .call(yAxis);
vis.selectAll('rect')
  .data(barData)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', function (d) {
    return xRange(d.x);
  })
  .attr('y', function (d) {
    return yRange(d.y);
  })
  .attr('width', xRange.rangeBand())
  .attr('height', function (d) {
    return ((HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) - yRange(d.y));
  })
  .attr('fill', 'grey')
  .on('mouseover',function(d){
    d3.select(this)
      .attr('fill','blue');
  })
  .on('mouseout',function(d){
    d3.select(this)
      .attr('fill','grey');
  })
  .on('click',function(d){
      d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();
    child ? InitChart(dataC) : InitChart([d], true);
  });
}
```

css:

```
 .axis path, .axis line
    {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #777;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .axis text
    {
        font-family: 'Arial';
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    .tick
    {
        stroke-dasharray: 1, 2;
    }
    .bar
    {
        fill: FireBrick;
    }
```

here a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/277ztbux/)